# Is the phrase "Next waiting!" by retail staff incorrect grammar?

Tags: grammar, idioms, colloquialisms

In Australian retail stores the phrase *"Next waiting!"* has become an idiom.

As I understand it, it is a contraction of *"Can I serve the person **next waiting**?"*.

When the idiom is used, it is snapped out in a tone that you might use for *"get over here!"*. Something about its usage jars in my sense of the English language.

My question is: **Is the phrase *"Next waiting!"* by retail staff incorrect grammar?**

Comment: Arguably, it's new grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With such a clipped phrase, I don't think you can worry about incorrect grammar.  Yes, depending how it's uttered, it can mean "Next!" [brusquely] or "Next, please!".

Answer (score 2):

Well, it ought to pretty clear that it's superficially ungrammatical. Nominally, English sentences require (at a minimum) a noun and a verb, and this has neither.

That said, of course, since it's obviously a massive contraction, the implied terms are obvious, and under the circumstances there is no danger of it being misunderstood, it should be just as acceptable as other massive contractions such as "Yes." or "No."

Answer (score 0):

It's not incorrect because it is not a complete sentence. We often say things that are not a complete sentence. For instance, imagine the staff member yelling "Next person!". That no doubt feels more correct (if still not particularly polite!). Similarly they could yell out "First person!" or "Young people!" or "Sarah and Jen!" or "Passengers in row seven!" or any other noun phrase that attracts the attention of the people they are after.

The issue is that "Next waiting!" is essentially two adjectives in a row without the noun they are operating on. It is an incomplete noun phrase. In this circumstance, that noun is presumably meant to be "person", but in different contexts it could be "taxi" or "team" or something else. If you imagine someone yelling out "Next young!", it feels wrong for the same reason. Your brain expects the second word to be a noun but it is not.

Technically, "waiting" is a participle acting as an adjective. But that's not especially relevant. The reason it feels wrong is because "waiting" is not a noun, and that's what the listener is expecting.